# Can I use every thread my system has to offer at once?

Tags: multithreading

I am writing a C++ program that will have multithreading as a major part of it to speed up some tasks. However, since I have 8 threads on my processor accessible to me, I was wondering if I can actually use all 8 simultaneously? Would it actually speed things up if I only used 7 so that my OS can use the 8th thread without fighting for processing power and slowing things down?

For the moment my code is running on Ubuntu if that makes any difference. The task involve my threads taking in a handful of data, doing a ton of number crunching, then saving the results directly to disk from the thread. I've tested a similar thread-to-disk approach before in a different project of mine, and my SSD can handle this no problem with the threads going, although my HDD bottlenecks (Quite honestly, kinda expected that).

So mainly I'm just wondering if it is good practice to reserve a thread or two to allow my OS to run unimpeded, or if there's going to be no functional difference and I just ramp my code all the way to running on the max number of threads my system has

Comment: It depends... You can write apps that use multiple threads/processes; and sometimes that'll make things faster; but sometimes it'll slow things down.  It depends what the limiting factor is (i.e. if you're waiting on a response from a DB that's not going to come back any quicker), if you're doing purely computational tasks can they be broken down easily / do you need to stitch things back together / etc.  We'd need to know a lot more about your specific scenario to say.

Comment: Just to clarify the terminology, CPUs don't have threads, they have cores. You can run 8 threads literally simultaneously on 8 cores, but you can (and will) have many more threads active at the same time - the O/S schedules threads automatically to run on the available cores as needed, so you don't need to explicitly reserve any.

Comment: If possible, it's good to make the number of threads variable with something like a thread pool. Then you can bench mark your application. CPU bound threads shouldn't exceed the number of cores because you'll start using more overhead to manage the threads. Threads that have to wait for resources, you can use more threads than available cores and you let the OS handle the scheduling.

Comment: We cannot answer this question in your case since there is not enough information in the question for that. In general, the answer depends on a lot of factors so the target code, target OS, and target platforms are mandatory informations so to provide a precise answer. Indeed, not all code scale (none scale infinitely in practice) and using more cores do not means a faster execution. In fact, modern mainstream processors like Intel/AMD ones use frequency scaling for the power/energy budget to be fulfilled : using more cores reduce the frequency of each core.

Comment: In fact, on Intel processor, this frequency scaling is dependent of what the code does : parallel AVX code typically operate at a lower frequency than SSE code or scalar ones. As for the scalability of IO operations, this is a huge topic too. Their scalability depends on the OS API layer used, the access pattern, the actual storage device used (not just the kind of storage device). Results can be drastically different from one platform to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term "thread" in programming is different from the term "thread" as used in CPU design. When you run a multi-threaded program, you're effectively telling the operating system "here are the operations that I want to do in parallel". The operating system then *schedules* the threads by deciding which CPU core should run them (and if you have threaded CPUs, which of the core's threads), but there isn't a 1-to-1 correspondence; for example, if the operating system needs one CPU core for its own purposes, then it'll just use it itself, and put the threads of your program onto the other cores; even if there are more threads than cores, the operating system will simply put multiple threads on a single core and have the CPU alternate between them. (Operating systems will typically also move your threads from one core to another over the course of execution, in order to help balance how much the various cores are being used.)

This means that optimising a multi-threaded program for performance isn't as simple as creating a fixed number of software threads based on the number of CPU cores you have – sometimes, a lower number is good due to overhead in the threading mechanism, and sometimes, it's optimal to have a number of threads that's substantially greater than the number of CPU cores on the system (because this gives the OS more flexibility as to how to schedule them). As such, people generally recommend benchmarking various numbers of threads to see which is fastest for any given program.

If you're concerned about the threads of your program overwhelming the other tasks that the computer is trying to perform, there's an alternative approach to trying to fix that problem – on most operating systems, you can set a thread's *priority*. In cases where there are more threads trying to run than the CPU can handle simultaneously, lower-priority threads will be given less CPU time in order to reserve more CPU time for higher-priority threads. Lowering the priority of all your program's threads can thus be useful if it's causing the system to be less responsive when run.

My recommendation is to start by running the program with a number of threads equal to the maximum number your CPU can run simultaneously (8 in your case), but it's probably also worth bench-marking that number minus 1 (7) and 1.5 times that number (12) to see if either of those work better. (I'd also look at the computer's CPU utilisation when running the benchmarks – if your program is I/O-bound rather than CPU-bound, then the CPU won't be able to run at full capacity no matter how many threads you have, and in that case you might be able to run the CPU part of your program at full speed even with fewer threads than cores.)

If the computer becomes insufficiently responsive as a consequence, try lowering the program's priority first (technically: the priority of all the program's threads), and if that doesn't work, only then should you try lowering the number of threads (or banning them from using a specific CPU) in order to prevent them causing performance issues.